# DRF using prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-queryset

I have two classes Vessels and Components, each vessel has several components.
I just want to fetch all vessels and all their related components in one query, I thought prefretch_related does that trick but in DRF in the api i am only receiving the vessels without their related components

models.py

```
class Vessel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    imo = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Component(models.Model):
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(
        Vessel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vessel_components')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
class VesselSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vessel
        fields = '__all__'
class ComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = '__all__'
```

the view :

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getVessels(request):
    vessels = Vessel.objects.all().prefetch_related('vessel_components')
    vSerializer = VesselSerializer(vessels, many=True)
    return Response(vSerializer.data)
```

the result i am getting :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought `prefretch_related` does that trick but in DRF.

This will fetch the `Component`s for the `Vessel`s, but since your serializers do not serialize these components, these will not end up in the result.

You should define the `ComponentSerializer` as subserializer for `VesselSerializer`, so:

```
class ComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = '__all__'

class VesselSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vessel_components = ComponentSerializer(many=True)  # 🖘 subserializer
    
    class Meta:
        model = Vessel
        fields = '__all__'
```